# Does battery drain faster if I don't use 'Lock Screen' feature?

Tags: lock-screens

Questions explains it all. I don't use any kind of lock screen on my phone. A home screen appears directly if I wake up the screen. So what's better? Using lock screen or not using it.
*Note - Security is not my concern.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lock screen uses widgets, like weather, news aggregators, notifications, etc, then it's likely to use more battery.

Personally, I just use the plain swipe lock screen without additional widgets.

Comment: Yeah thanks for replying. My lock screen uses only two widgets by default namely - Camera, Digital clock and I have an option of including more widgets like Gmail, Whatsapp etc... but I don't use'em. I can disable Camera widget also. But I don't want to use lock screen anymore. My home screen also has no widgets at all because I like my wallpaper to be fully visible. So using Home Screen instead of lock screen is okay right?

Comment: @MANI Yeah, it's OK. But you take the risk of having your data compromised if you lose your phone (e.g. somebody steals it).

Comment: Nobody can separate me from my phone ;)
Thanks for dropping by...

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference. Even if you have home screen or lock screen widgets that cause battery-draining activity, such as an email widget that checks for email very frequently, this background activity will happen regardless of whether the widget is on screen.

The only difference it'll make is that if you often wake up your phone for short periods on the day (say, just to check Facebook quickly), the screen on the phone will be on for a few seconds longer while you unlock it. That won't add up to much over the course of a year.

Really, the biggest difference is that if you have the lock screen turned off and you manage to pocket-dial someone, or start a game in your pocket, that'll be using a lot of battery that could have been avoided if you have a lock screen. If there's any risk of you doing this, then *on average* having the lock screen turned off will drain your battery faster.

Comment: I've no widgets on home screen (only one home screen). It's clean. Lock screen has a digital clock, a shortcut for camera, and an option of adding more widgets. So now it makes any difference?

Comment: Was my answer not clear? It doesn't matter whether you have widgets or not.

Comment: It's clear man. I'll mark the answer in a moment. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure? Widgets drain battery if it's on the home screen or lock screen. Remove the widgets, and it drains lesser battery. So, it matters.

Comment: @geffchang The question's not whether they drain battery at all: it depends on the particular widget. The question's whether turning the lock screen on or off affects the power consumption. Having widgets isn't a factor in that: the widgets will cost the same amount of battery either way.

Answer (score 0):

As you have no widgets on either lockscreen or homescreen the difference would be marginal, purely caused by the fact the screen is on for a shorter amount of time and therefore using less battery